# Synchronizing SVN servers - advanced setup

Tags: svn

I have a semi-complex SVN setup that I need to configure. There is already a SVN repository that a third-party company is working on. We have to create a local repository that pulls and merges code from theirs, 3 virtual machines that are working copies of the whole production environment on which the devs are going to code on and commit to the local repo, and a production VM that only pulls from the local repo.

I need a way to make the local repository pull code from the remote one while providing a way to review changed files from our local commits, so remote changes don't overwrite our work.

[image: SVN diagram]

Comment: Check your options in SVNBook. Reading SVNBook is strongly recommended prior to starting to implement the solution. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is getting a bit complex. I take it you don't want your local repo to be read-only which makes syncing your remote repository to your local so difficult. Most svnsync schemes depend upon the two being exact duplicates of each other.

You'll need to keep track of your last sync revision from your remote repository and use `svnrdump dump` to pull out a dump of the unsynced transactions from the remote repository. I haven't done this, but it doesn't look too bad. However, you'll have to shut down your local repository in order to deliver your remote revisions, and you must make sure that the local and remote are on two different URLs.

Comment: Is it possible to setup a client bot that pulls from the remote repo and pushes the files to the local one, checking if the mtime of the original files it had is the same as the mtime of the files on the local repo? If they differ, don't push those to local, but inform the devs about the conflict. Or something along those lines...

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov - There's no _mtime_ on files in the repository. You really need to track the last revision pulled from the remote, and download the newer revisions. The revision numbers will differ between the local and remote repository, so there's no real way to tell that way. I guess you could look at the timestamp of the change and compare it to the timestamp of the change on the local repository, but I think you're better off just tracking the revisions pulled.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov - yes, **partially only**, with some tricks and *special* preparation of LocalRepo

Answer (score 0):

It's a time to move to DVCS, really. Migration from SVN to Mercurial isn't big headache and solve problem of multiply related repos (**any** amount of repos) for the cost of two commands.

But, if you still prefer SVN-way (bad way in this situation):

- If MASTER can be reached from LOCAL you can use svn commands with MASTER URL and get results) you can build and use "Vendor Branch" workflow

  - MASTER tree (/trunk ?) mounted into LOCAL repository at some node (outside LOCAL's trunk), using svn:externals
  - local development happens in trunk, as usual
  - changes from MASTER must be integrated into trunk from time to time using obvious merge
- If MASTER can't be reached from LOCAL, but svn-client (svn on notebook), which can communicate with both repositories, still can be found

  - LOCAL **must** be created from MASTER dump with **saving MASTER's UUID** on load stage
  - LOCAL's development must happen not in trunk, but any other custom branch
  - client have to a) checkout|update own WC from MASTER b) relocate WC to LOCAL c) commit changes to LOCAL (probably collapsing source revisions)
  - MASTER changes from LOCAL trunk haveto be merged to the development branch